# I was trying to get HDMI to work and broke the video drivers that broke UEFI and I can't get back to where I was and I can't install any updates

Tags: uefi, hdmi

I have a ConceptD that has only Ubuntu 22.04 on it I was trying to get HDMI working so I "fooled" with the video drivers.  That caused some sort of UEFI error and I rebooted and skipped MOK enrollment out of ignorance.  Now I can't move forward or back and the BIOS won't let me edit secure boot or UEFI.  That causes all updates to return this error

---

Package configuration

```
 ┌────────────────────────┤ Configuring Secure Boot ├────────────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                   
 │                                                                             
 │ UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with             
 │ third-party drivers.                                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit       
 │ the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been      
 │ generated. This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.     
 │                                                                             
 │ To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user,      
 │ and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm     
 │ the change after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll        
 │ MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you     
 │ when this system reboots.                                                   
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>                                       
 │                                                                           │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Please list the exact steps you did to break it.

Comment: Did you try turning UEFI Secure Boot off? If using proprietary video drivers you have to create your own key MOK - machine owners key to say that driver is secure. And if changing drivers you must purge before adding a new one.

Comment: I first tried to change to a proprietary nvidia driver that prompted a MOK prompt on a restart.  I ignored that because I didn't understand the significance.  I instead tried to go back to the original  drivers which are working. But  now I get the following issue constantly. It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager "Synaptic" or run "sudo apt-get install -f" in a terminal to fix this issue at first.

Comment: I would love to turn UEFI Secure boot off if I could find a way to do that

Comment: So I set a UEFI password to boot and then I was able to disable Secure boot.  I'm not sure about the update issue yet but progress

Comment: After fixing UEFI I ran sudo apt-get install -f  followed by sudo apt-get update.  Then when the system prompted for a partial update it ran to completion.  It is early yet but this seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to `<OK>` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

So I set a UEFI password to boot and then I was able to disable Secure boot.

After fixing UEFI I ran sudo apt-get install -f followed by sudo apt-get update. Then when the system prompted for a partial update it ran to completion.